# Python decorator skips the code of the decorated function

Tags: python, decorator

This code skips the code in the `number` function:

```
def some_decorator(x):
     def wrapper(x):
         return x+1
     return wrapper

@some_decorator
def number(x):
    x = x + 100
    return x
```

Output:

```
>>> number(3)
4
```

I am trying to make the output of `number(3)` to be 104, what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorators pass the function as an argument to the decorator. It's your job to call the function if you want it to execute:

```
def some_decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(x):
         return fn(x) + 1 # call the function and add 1 
    return wrapper

@some_decorator
def n(x):
    x = x + 100
    return x

n(3) # 104
```

As a side note, it's often useful to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to make the wrapped function behave as expected:

```
from functools import wraps

def some_decorator(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(x):
         return fn(x) + 1
    return wrapper

@some_decorator
def n(x):
    x = x + 100
    return x

print(n.__name__) # now prints `n` instead of `wrapper`
```